# iOS 8 html input file control black screen when selected "Take Photo" option

Tags: html, ios, iphone, file, input

Does anybody face problem of black screen when selected the option to "Take Photo" on iOS 8 with html input file control?

For example, if you try http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_fileupload_get

click on "choose file" on iOS 8 (iphone 6 device) select "Take Photo" option, the screen goes black.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

In case if anybody faces the same problem, enable safari to access camera under Settings>Privacy>Camera. Somehow on my device it is disabled, may be i must have disabled it at some point and forgot it.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the game, but I was having a similar issue. iOS requires camera access to be over SSL to work properly, otherwise you'll just get a blacked out camera UI.

Comment: sorry to comment an old post, but I get the blacked camera only when the web app goes to background and it comes back in foreground. Otherwise, the first time, the camera works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Giacomo that it is related to the app losing focus, i.e. going into the background.  To restore operation, you have to close the app then re-launch.  Once another app takes the foreground, the camera stops.    At least this is true of PWA apps.

ios 13.4 resolves this.